# Laravel, decoding with CCSID for passed parameter

Tags: php, laravel, nan

In laravel 5.8, I'm attempting to pass an ID that is being sent to the front-end (shown in console) as a 26 byte string "0213725502A340576F8E218001". In the database, it's a `character(13)` value that looks like `13B<-0000000 02 13 72 etc`

I'm seeing the 26 byte version and passing it in a URL but when I land on the URL I get NaN as the value.

What do I need to do to properly use/decode this for use in the URL?

I know it uses a CCSID if that's helpful

code:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a v-bind:href="+dateEvent.item_id+'/progress'">Details</a></button></td>
```

Comment: Well, it's not a number, so it makes sense it'd result in NaN in JavaScript if you're trying to do numbers work on it. What code causes the NaN error?

Comment: Updated with code, the ```dateEvent.item_id``` is the id in question

Comment: Try removing the leading `+` before `dateEvent.item_id`. That looks like a typo.

Comment: You may be right. I did remove that, still the same issue though